# Hibernate: How to set mapped by attribute when the Many side of the Many to one relationship is maintained in an object in an embedded collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a 2 entities and an embedded object. To keep the discussion generic, I am going to call them Project, ProjectAssociation (embedded object), employee.

Employees are associated to Project using a project association.

My business requirement is such that I should be able to lookup projectAssociation from employee. Furthermore, in the future we can expect the projectAssociation to gain more attributes. The lifecycle of projectAssociation will always be tied to project.

The Project and employee entities have a many to many relationship between them via the projectAssociation embedded object.

How do I have the mapped by configured from project to project association.?

```
Employee {
    Project projects;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="What to set here?")
    public Set<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }

    public void setProjects(Set<Project> projects) {
        this.projects= projects;
    }
}

Project {
    Set<ProjectAssociation> projectAssocs;

    @Embedded
    @ElementCollection
    public Set<ProjectAssociation> getProjectAssociation() {
        return projectAssocs;
    }

    public void setProjectAssociation(Set<ProjectAssociation> hostRecovery) {
        this.projectAssocs = projectAssocs;
    }
}

ProjectAssociation {
// Parent association variable and methods are omitted for brevity
    Employee  employee;

    @ManyToOne
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need ProjectAssociation object? Why not make relation between Project and Employee @ManyToMany and use join table? This way we eliminate unnecessary class and make our code cleaner.

Comment: @popfalushi he said that there are going to be many more attributes in ProjectAssociation.

Comment: I'm not sure about the question unless it exists only in the title. If that is the case, then why would you include the association in the equals and hashcode? The idea of a many to many is that there is only one instance for a unique project and one for a unique employee. Since they are already unique, why further qualify with associations?

Comment: @Thom. Thanks for the reply. You are right. THe disconnect was because I started of by making projectAssociation an entity in itself. Then changed the approach to collection of embedded objects. I will draft that as a seperate question and post it soon.

Comment: Folks, I have changed the title. Hope that helps clarify the actual question here. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @popfalushi Yes an approach might be to model the join table as an entity and have many to one relationships to both the project and employee. However, as per the domain, projectAssociation lifecycle is tied to Project. 

I can use cascades to get a similar effect. however, I am hoping that there is a way to use embedded objects here.

Answer (score 0):

you need to map it as @ManyToMany with the intermediate table and the foreign key columns, then set Inverse() so that Employee doesnt maintain any linktable entries

```
@ManyToMany(...)
@Inverse()
public Set<Project> getProjects() {
    return projects;
}
```